# Is it possible to set custom DNS resolver in C#'s HttpClient

Tags: c#, .net, dns, dotnet-httpclient

what exactly I want :

```
public static CustomDnsResolver : Dns 
{
   .....
}

public static void Main(string[] args) 
{
    var httpClient = new HttpClient();
    httpClient.Dns(new CustomDnsResolver());
}
```

basically I just want to use my custom DNS resolver in HttpClient instead of System default, Is there any way to achieve it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The use case you have is exactly why Microsoft build the HttpClient stack. It allow you to put your business logic in layered class with the help of `HttpMessageHandler` class. You can find some sample in [ms docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/apps/hh781241(v=win.10)) or [visualstudiomagazine](https://visualstudiomagazine.com/articles/2014/08/01/creating-custom-httpclient-handlers.aspx)

```
async Task Main()
{
    var dnsHandler = new DnsHandler(new CustomDnsResolver());
    var client = new HttpClient(dnsHandler);
    var html = await client.GetStringAsync("http://google.com");
}

public class DnsHandler : HttpClientHandler
{
    private readonly CustomDnsResolver _dnsResolver;

    public DnsHandler(CustomDnsResolver dnsResolver)
    {
        _dnsResolver = dnsResolver;
    }
    
    protected override Task<HttpResponseMessage> SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        var host = request.RequestUri.Host;
        var ip = _dnsResolver.Resolve(host);
        
        var builder = new UriBuilder(request.RequestUri);
        builder.Host = ip;
        
        request.RequestUri = builder.Uri;
        
        return base.SendAsync(request, cancellationToken);
    }
}

public class CustomDnsResolver
{
    public string Resolve(string host)
    {
        return "127.0.0.1";
    }
}
```

### More advanced version based on [Meziantou blog post](https://www.meziantou.net/creating-an-httpclient-that-uses-dns-over-https.htm)

```cs
async Task Main()
{
    var dnsResolver = new CustomDnsResolver();

    var sockerHttpHandler = new SocketsHttpHandler()
    {
        ConnectCallback = async (context, cancellationToken) =>
        {
            var ipAddress = dnsResolver.Resolve(context.DnsEndPoint.Host);
            

            var socket = new Socket(SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp)
            {
                // Turn off Nagle's algorithm since it degrades
                // performance in most HttpClient scenarios.
                NoDelay = true
            };

            try
            {
                await socket.ConnectAsync(
                    ipAddress,
                    context.DnsEndPoint.Port,
                    cancellationToken);
                return new NetworkStream(socket, ownsSocket: true);
            }
            catch
            {
                socket.Dispose();
                throw;
            }
        },
    };

    var client = new HttpClient(sockerHttpHandler);
    var html = await client.GetStringAsync("https://google.com");
}

public class CustomDnsResolver
{
    public IPAddress Resolve(string host)
    {
        return IPAddress.Parse("216.58.214.164");
    }
}
```

Comment: This solution doesn't work if you try to fetch data from https site.

Comment: You can override certificate validation to workaroud this.

Comment: you can override the ServerCertificateCustomValidationCallback of HttpClientHandler to custom certificate validation

Comment: This doesn't answer the question. You cannot just say, "override certificate validation", what is expected is that we set the hostname correctly so SSL works but avoid the DNS lookup.

Comment: This answer is true for a set of constrains. I don't propose you the universal answer. If it can help some people as is. I'm still happy. If someone else can propose a better answer, I will thanks him for that.

Comment: Indeed, we can walkaround the certificate validation via other ways. But actually we've met another question, when server side accepts ONLY request from hostname instead of IP, this solution fails. :-(

Comment: You can try this also https://www.meziantou.net/creating-an-httpclient-that-uses-dns-over-https.htm. I'll try to updated my answer with it.

Answer (score 7):

Not sure if this works for all cases, but it worked brilliantly for my case, even when using HTTPS. So what you do is you replace the host in the URL with the actual IP-address that your custom resolver has resolved, and then you simply add a "host" header with the host name. Like this:

```
        var requestUri = new Uri("https://123.123.123.123/some/path");
        using var request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Get, requestUri);
        request.Headers.TryAddWithoutValidation("host", "www.host-name.com");
        using var response = await httpClient.SendAsync(request);
```

I hope this helps as this is far by the first time I've run into this issue and I've never been able to solve it before now.

Comment: This will work for https only if you also override certificate errors as mentioned in the comment by Dylech30th on the other answer.

Comment: Hm... I actually use this is production today and it works like a charm. I don't override certificate errors in any way. I use the SocketsHttpHandler and run in .NET 6. How can that be?

Comment: After some experimentation, your code **does work** as long as there is a valid certificate for www.host-name.com available for the web server at 123.123.123.123 to use for TLS negotiation.  If there is no such certificate at the address, you'll get an error. Example here https://pastebin.com/vDjGBfHC

Comment: I've done some digging in on the behavioral change of the SocketsHttpHandler, as you can see in https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/45144, the actual reason is that the server requires SNI validation, before .NET 5, the host header will not be used as the SNI automatically, but this behavior changed in .NET 5 where it now forces host header as the SNI if it is set.

Answer (score 2):

Consider using [SocketsHttpHandler.ConnectCallback](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.http.socketshttphandler.connectcallback?view=net-5.0#System_Net_Http_SocketsHttpHandler_ConnectCallback).